# logging to console using cucumber & Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

i'm building some test scenarios and steps using cucumber and rails

for example here's a simple code to check and uncheck checkboxes in the page i want to log what is happening like a sort of debugging :

```
When /^I (un)?check all ratings$/ do |uncheck|
  page.all("[type='checkbox']").each do |checkbox|
    if !uncheck
      check(checkbox[:id])
      #i want Here to log which checkboxes are checked
    else
      uncheck(checkbox[:id])          
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you're looking for is logging to stdout, it's as simple as just putting a `puts` in your steps.

But you can put arbitrary ruby of any kind in your steps, so you can open a file and write to that, or use a ruby `Logger`, or anything really. The sky's the limit.